# Is there any possibility of getting some part of summary band data in one page and other part of summary band data in next page in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working with jasper reports and i am getting the data well but my problem is i am getting the data in 2 to 3 pages summary band data is big and it is printing in a new page. I will show an image for better understanding.

[image]

and second page is
[image]

so my question now is there any possibility of getting some part of summary band in one page and other part in next page

Comment: Are you  still having problem with this one?

Comment: @PetterFriberg No,i haven't tried that,because we are under discussion on what to do with the summary band

Comment: @PetterFriberg  I got a doubt. like <break> component can be auto matically be taken by jasper report irrespective of a person giving that component in jasper report. I will explain with an example. If in summary band i have 10 static fields and 10 text fields. If detail band data is big then 8 static fields and 8 text fields will be printed in first page and remaining in other page. If the data in detail band is small,then summary band data is filled in one page. Like these,is there any flexibility of printing the data with out using <break> component  in jasper reports

Comment: Instead of summary band try with group bands on this you can set attribute minHeightToStartNewPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved by using the `<break>` component when you like to have the page break. [JRBreak API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRBreak.html)

es.

```
<summary>
    <band height="68">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="73b59f4e-2a74-48ec-b152-ca705bb98fd8"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Summary page 1"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <break>
            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="100" height="1" uuid="3aa84342-4219-47c2-9724-96284afcd9b3"/>
        </break>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="26" width="100" height="20" uuid="0306db4f-ba7f-4ff5-ac18-a9e5d42cdbda"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Summary page 2"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Note: If the summary band is to **start** on a new page is controlled by attribute `isSummaryNewPage` on the `<jasperReport>` tag

`isSummaryNewPage="true"` start `summary` band on new page

`isSummaryNewPage="false"`, don't start the `summary` band on new page (if there is space on current page)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is **no  "Break" element** accidentally added in the summary band.